# SOAP Web Service Client conflcts with xfire

Tags: soap, xfire

I generated wsdl using wsimport from JDK 1.6. I then wrote a client to invoke the web service I got the following error.

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Service.
    at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.ServiceDelegate.<init>(ServiceDelegate.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.xfire.jaxws.Provider.createServiceDelegate(Provider.java:32)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
```

Then I removed xfire-all 1.2.6 jar used in my
 application and found it working but only if the class was invoked from command  line and not from application functionality which is the real need as removing xfire jar is not an option for me..Please help I read numberyyy of posts but did not get any fruitful solution yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: One question is xfire-all 1.2.6 supportive of jax-ws api?.